`--single-transaction` equivalent for mysqlsh util.dumpSchema
My database is using InnoDB, and when using mysqldump I have the option to set --single-transaction to avoid locking the tables while still having a consistent view of them.
I'm trying to switch over to the recommended MySQL Shell util.dumpSchema, and I only see two options: consistent: true and consistent: false. The documentation for consistent: true specifies that the tables will be locked for backup.
Is it possible to use util.dumpSchema to dump in a single transaction via InnoDB in the same way? Or is this done automatically if the tables use InnoDB?
